# iOS UITableView won't show anything when loading data from Dropbox

Tags: ios, uitableview, dropbox

I have a UITableView thats supposed to show the contents of a folder from dropbox when it loads. I know its getting the data from dropbox by using log statements. I reload the data in the table after it gets the data from drop box but it still shows nothing. Please help

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    uploadFileButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(uploadFile:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = uploadFileButton;
    self.title = @"DropBox";

    [[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/"];
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

    for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
        NSLog(@"\t%@", file.filename);
        [dropBoxArray addObject:file.filename];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", dropBoxArray);

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [dropBoxArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text);

    return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind i got it. This was the correct call to load metadata:

```
[[self restClient] loadMetadata:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to show ProcessIndicator while you are making request

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    uploadFileButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(uploadFile:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = uploadFileButton;
    self.title = @"DropBox";

    [[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/"];
    [self showProcessIndicator]; //Your code for showing ProcessIndicator
}
```

And Hide when u get this method called.

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

    for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
        NSLog(@"\t%@", file.filename);
        [dropBoxArray addObject:file.filename];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", dropBoxArray);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self hideProcessIndicator];
    }
```

This will definitely solve your problem. 
Have a happy Coding ;)

Comment: thanks for answering, but I haven't worked on this since February. and I was asking how to load the files from dropbox. thanks though.